# pySpark Window Functions

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a data (df_1) with following scheme,

```
|-- Column1: string (nullable = true)
|-- Column2: string (nullable = true)
|-- Column3: long (nullable = true)
|-- Column4: double (nullable = true)
```

The type of df_1 being "pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame"

I want to create a new column as Rank which ranks the rows as per the window (security_window) function defined;

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
window=Window.partitionBy(F.col("Column1"),F.col('Column2')).orderBy(F.col("Column3"))).rangeBetween(-20,0)

df_1.withColumn('Rank',F.rank().over(window))
```

However, when I use this window function with mentioned dataframe (df_1),
I face following exception as AnalysisException. Anyone know what can be the cause?

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Window Frame RANGE BETWEEN 20 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW must match the required frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

Comment: try changing `rangeBetween` to [`rowsBetween`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween)? Possibly related: [SPARK-16642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16642)

Comment: I did that changed to ```rowsBetween``` from ```rangeBetween``` still it persist the same thing @pault